# Primefaces, scrollPanel with selectManyCheckbox

Tags: checkbox, primefaces, scroll

How I can use a p:scrollpanel with checkboxes, i've tried like this, but it isn't worked:

```
    <p:scrollPanel mode="native" >
                <h:panelGrid>
                    <p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{localCobrancaBean.selectLocaisCobranca}"> 

                        <f:selectItems value="#{localCobrancaBean.listaLocalCobranca}" />  

                    </p:selectManyCheckbox>
                </h:panelGrid>

            </p:scrollPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested using the following JSF:

```
<p:scrollPanel mode="native">
    <h:panelGrid>
        <p:selectManyCheckbox>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="asdfghgfd" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="zdvdfbdfvds" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="zdcdghnfw" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="sddfvdfv" />
        </p:selectManyCheckbox>
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:scrollPanel>
```

This was the result:

[image: checkbox vertical scroll]

So it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

the solution seems to me to set scrollpanel mode to native. the problem is about the relative and absolute positioning of scrollpanel and selectmanycheckbox DOM

Answer (score 0):

In my application, i have used below set of code to get multiple checkbox list with scrollbar:

```
<style type="text/css">
#productCategoryId label {
  float: inherit;
  font-size: 10px!important;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#productCategoryId table.formTable th, table.formTable td {
  padding: 0px 0px 0 0;
}
</style>

<div style="width:200px;height: 280px;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;border:1px solid #999;" max-height=280px>
             <h:selectManyCheckbox  id="productCategoryId" layout="pageDirection" style="width:200px" styleClass="changeId">
                  <f:selectItem itemValue="-1000" itemLabel="ALL" />
                  <f:selectItems value="#{lookup.list['RSM_LOOKUP']['PRODUCT_CATEGORY']}"/>
                </h:selectManyCheckbox >
            </div>
```